# SWI-Prolog predicate example part 2

Tags: prolog

Can someone please help me in transforming this to match this updated requirement?

> Define a predicate `strikeDuplicates(X,Y)` that succeeds if and only the list `Y` would
>   be obtained if one were to remove the second and subsequent occurrences of each element
>   from list `X`. (You might read `strikeDuplicates (X,Y)` as *list `X` without duplicates
>   is list `Y`.*) The `strikeDuplicates/2` predicate need not work well when `X` is an
>   unbound variable.

I asked a similar question two days ago asking this:

> Define a predicate `strike(X,Y,Z)` that succeeds if and only if the list `Z` would be
>   obtained if one were to remove all occurrences of element `X` from list `Y`. The
>   `strike/3` predicate need not work well when `Y` is an unbound variable.

No one helped me so I had to do it by myself. That answer was this:

```
strike( _ , []    , []    ) .
strike( X , [X|T] , Z     ) :-            strike(X,T,Z) .
strike( X , [A|T] , [A|Z] ) :- dif(X,A) , strike(X,T,Z) .

dif(X,A).
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Your definition of the auxiliary predicate `dif/2` is wrong. For example, `dif(1,1)` is true. You can replace it by a call to the standard term equality predicate, `(\==)/2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that doesn't preserve order is:

```
strike_duplicates([], []).
strike_duplicates([X| Xs], List) :-
    (   member(X, Xs) ->
        strike_duplicates(Xs, List)
    ;   List = [X| Tail],
        strike_duplicates(Xs, Tail)
    ).
```

To preserve order, you need to keep track of the elements found so far while you traverse the list. A solution would be:

```
strip_duplicates(List, Set) :-
    strip_duplicates(List, [], Set).

strip_duplicates([], _, []).
strip_duplicates([X| Xs], Found, List) :-
    (   member(X, Found) ->
        strip_duplicates(Xs, Found, List)
    ;   List = [X| Tail],
        strip_duplicates(Xs, [X| Found], Tail)
    ).
```

The predicate `member/2` is usually either a built-in predicate or available as a library predicate. Check your Prolog system documentation if necessary.

Comment: Could you use the variables and the predicate name i expressed in the question?

Comment: I changed the predicate name as you asked from `strip_duplicates/2` to `strike_duplicates/2`. It's considered bad programming style in Prolog to use CamelCase for predicate names. The use of underscores help readability.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the rule predicate does not need to express anything about the variable Y then?

Comment: Not "rule predicate" but "predicate clause" or "predicate rule". Variables in Prolog are **logical** variables, they don't work as e.g. variables in imperative languages. Moreover, logical variables are **local** to a predicate clause.

Comment: Thank you my friend and I will test this predicate but I am sure it looks very well done and you did a good job explaining it, I do thank you :)

Comment: Hey it seems not to work, I open the code in prolog and i test a value such as strikeDuplicates([1,3,3,2,1,1,2],[1,3,2]).  it says false, but if your code is right it should be true? Why is that?

Comment: Can you get to this comment as soon as possible?

Comment: strikeDuplicates([1,3,3,2,1,1,2],[1,3,2]) should succeed 
because if one were to remove from the first list all 1’s but the first 1, all 3’s 
but the first 3, and all 2’s but the first 2, one would obtain 
[1,3,3,2,1,1,2], which is [1,3,2]. (The strikethroughs, such as 2, 
indicate elements that would be removed from list X to form list Y.)

Comment: I didn't notice the order requirement. Edited my reply accordingly.

Comment: Thanks man it works great, me and my classmate thank you :) your good

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easy way would be to use the built-in predicate `setof/3`, but I suspect that's not what your professor wants.

Think about the problem for a second or two. A clear *problem statement* is often helpful (and in Prolog is often the solution itself):

To make the source list a *set* (unique elements) instead of a *bag* (allows duplication), you'll have to

- Iterate over the source list
- Track items you've already seen (the 'visited' list)
- Add each item to the visited list only if  the visited list doesn't already contain it.

Once you've done that you've got the desired result.

Here's a hint: a very common prolog idiom is the use of *helper predicates* that carry with it an *accumulator*. Often the helper predicate has the same *functor*, but a different *arity*. For example, to sum the values in a list (`sum/2`) we can use a helper `sum/3` that carries an accumulator, seeded with 0:

```
sum(Xs,N) :- sum(Xs,0,N).

sum([],S,S).
sum([N|Ns],T,S) :-
  T1 is T+N,
  sum(Ns,T1,S)
  .
```

You'll notice how unfication with the result is *deferred* until the final value has been computed.

You need to do something like that but using as an accumulator an [empty] *list* that will be extended with the unique values you discover.

Another hint: the built-in predicate `member/2` will check if a term is a member of a list. It's written

```
member(X,[X|Xs]).
member(X,[_|Xs]) :- member(X,Xs).
```

So `member(2,[1,2,3])` is `true` whilst `member(2,[1,3])` is `false`.

Conversely, one can use `member/2` to successively return each element of a list via backtracking: `member(X,[1,2,3])` produces

```
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
false
```

Given those two notions, you should be able to figure out the solution. Come back and show us your code and we can help you. There is one other little `gotcha`, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: The most up to date solution i Have is the one Paulo Moura came up with but its not proving correct when I test it with a Unit Test

Comment: Nicholas, I removed my outdated comment and voted up your reply.